# set time in kernel space

Tags: time, linux-kernel, kernel

I apologize but I'm totally newbie...

I'm trying to write my own driver for custom hardware.
I need to read system time in kernel:

```
struct timeval time;
struct tm broken, mytime;

...
do_gettimeofday(&time);
time_to_tm(time.tv_sec, 0, &broken);
printk(KERN_INFO "Timer synced at %d:%d:%d:%ld\n", broken.tm_hour, broken.tm_min,broken.tm_sec, time.tv_usec);
...
```

and this works.

Then I manually set:
- broken.tm_hour
- broken.tm_min
...
- broken.tm_sec
- time.tv_usec

how can I now update system time with my values?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In user space there are couple functions: gettimeofday and settimeofday. May be do_settimeofday ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of fillings data into 'struct timespec', I am just keeping it simple:

**$ sudo insmod .ko hh=2 mm=50 ss=10 nn=600**

```
/*
=========================================================
Execute   :  sudo insmod <MODULENAME>.ko hh=2 mm=50 ss=10 nn=600
Output    :  dmesg
=========================================================
*/

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/time.h>

static int hh, mm, ss, nn;

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_param(hh, int, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(hr, "Hours");
module_param(mm, uint, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(mm, "Minutes");
module_param(ss, uint, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(ss, "Seconds");
module_param(nn, uint, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(nn, "Nano seconds");

int __init ourinitmodule(void)
{

    struct timeval time;
    struct tm broken;
    struct timespec tp;
    printk(KERN_ALERT "\nWelcome to Module .... \n");
    do_gettimeofday(&time);
    time_to_tm(time.tv_sec, 0, &broken);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Timer synced at %d:%d:%d:%ld\n", broken.tm_hour, broken.tm_min,broken.tm_sec, time.tv_usec);
    // Iam trying to set time to 2:50:10:800 (HH:MM:SS:NN)
    tp.tv_sec= 3600/*constant*/ * hh /*hours*/ + 60 * mm /*minutes*/ + ss  /*seconds*/;
    tp.tv_nsec=1000* nn /*nanosec*/;
    do_settimeofday(&tp);
    do_gettimeofday(&time);
    time_to_tm(time.tv_sec, 0, &broken);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Timer set to %d:%d:%d:%ld\n", broken.tm_hour, broken.tm_min,broken.tm_sec, time.tv_usec);
    return 0;
}

void __exit ourcleanupmodule(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Thanks....Exiting Module. \n");
}

module_init(ourinitmodule);
module_exit(ourcleanupmodule);
```

Hope you got what you need.
Happy programming :)