# Set system time in Linux kernel space

Tags: time, module, linux-kernel, system, invalid-argument

It looks obvious that there shouldn't be a problem to set the system time in a Linux kernel module. However, *do_settimeofday()* function always returns EINVAL (Invalid argument) in my module written for a 4.4 kernel. I tried the example in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446558/set-time-in-kernel-space), and got the same EINVAL (when I printed the result of *do_settimeofday()*. It's interesting, that *stime(2)* system call uses the same *do_settimeofday()* function in the kernel, and it always works.

Thanks for ideas and directions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c?v=4.4#L909), *do_settimeofday* returns EINVAL only if

- Its `timespec` parameter is incorrect (number of seconds is negative or number of nanoseconds is outside of interval [0,1 000 000 000)), or
- Setting given time value will broke monolitic time nature. Note, while the function is intended for update *real* time, it also modifies *monolitic* time by the same delta.

Comment: Thanks, @Tsyvarev. The first one is not the case. The second one is understandable, but what's the proper way of changing system time?
_stime_ uses the same _do_dettimeofday_ as per http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/time.c#L82.

Comment: Please, add **concrete** use case into your question. This use case should contain: 1. *Exact value* of timespec, which you fail to set with kernel's `do_settimeofday()`. 2. *Exact value* (same) of timespec, which you succeed to set with user's `stime()`.

Comment: OK, it works now, thanks! It did not like the time which is too far from the current time (as per your monotonic time reason). The example I mentioned (from the post at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446558/set-time-in-kernel-space]) obviously won't work since it does not calculate the epoch time!